# How to convert html code to javascript string for sending html mail with dynamic values for nodemailer transport

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, string, email

I have hundreds of lines of HTML code for an email template. I already use small HTML code by making it string and send mail using nodemailer. But now I have hundreds of line HTML code and have to convert it to javascript.

Is there a tool to convert bulk HTML lines of code to javascript? Doing it manually will be very complex.

Comment: Why do you need javascript code in mailers?. Hope you aware that email programs like `gmail`, 'outlook` and others will block these code by marking them suspicious?

Comment: @DavidR - I don't think he wants to send javascript per se - he wants to convert HTML to a string (node.js tag makes me think that)

Comment: assuming this is a node.js question (i.e. your bulk spammer is a node.js program) - why not just get the contents of an HTML file into a variable using the standard nodejs file reader

Comment: @JaromandaX will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my Friend Refer me online tool for Converting Bulk Line of Html Code to Javascript Variable

[Tool Link](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/string.html)

and it help me a Lot and solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of this http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jstohtml.shtml or https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-to-js

Comment: thanks @Arif for your effort but i am using this tool 'pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/string.html'; –

Comment: is there any way to convert javascript html string to html

Answer (score 0):

So easy, use this function, look:

```
function CodeToString() {
  var a = document.body.innerHTML;
  return a;
}
```

how to use?, look:

```
mail(CodeToString()); //mail is you custom function to sent email.
```

CodeToString() is the function for convert the html to string javascript.

good, luck.

Comment: thanks @genife for your effort but i am using this tool 'pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/string.html'; –

Answer (score 0):

You can use an online [JS escaper](http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html)

Comment: thanks chirag for your effort but i am using this tool  'http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/string.html'

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to convert a bunch of HTML lines to JS string but not manually for obvious tedious reasons.

You can try the [ES6 Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

you simply set a variable to equal all your HTML and wrap them in ``(where the tilde key is i dont know what its called lol) instead of '' or "" , and done. You don't even have to worry about concatenation(unless you are interspersing other variables).

then in your mail function, send the variable. I just did this in an application i am working with.

For example, say you have a BUNCH of HTML code(yes it can be hundreds or more.
As an example(Pseudo code), in your JS file, you do:

```
var htmlToJsString = ` <lots of html code here> `;
```

Then in your mail function simply add the "htmlToJsString " in the message area and done. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @somdow for your effort will definitely go through ES6 template literals